# How Observable is created in retrofit without calling it from scheduler?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I am working on rx-java and retrofit and I have some queries related to it.I am not able to understand that when we call below code then how Observable(Observable) is created ?
According to my understanding it should be called only during the time of scheduling and subscribing.

```
CryptocurrencyService cryptocurrencyService = retrofit.create(CryptocurrencyService.class);

Observable<Crypto> cryptoObservable = cryptocurrencyService.getCoinData("btc");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a call adapter method in **Retrofit Builder** which convert Call responses to corresponding one in RxJava

```
Retrofit.Builder()
         .client(okHttpClient)
         .baseUrl(baseUrl)
         .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
         .build()
```